# How to create a connector-connection-pool in Glassfish 3.1.2 with REST interface

Tags: rest, glassfish

For a remote administration of multiple Glassfish 3.1.2.2 instances I want to configure resource adapter connection pool and connector resources. These configuration can only be done after the resource adapter deployment.

All works if I do things with asadmin.

Get Access via REST works as expected.
Example:

```
curl --user admin:pwd -X GET -H "Accept: application/JSON" 
     http://localhost:4848/management/domain/resources/connector-connection-pool
```

Now I want to create a connection pool using the following command with REST

```
asadmin create-connector-connection-pool --raname MulticastDNS-connector
         --connectiondefinition multicastdns.outbound.MulticastDNSRegistry multicastdns/pool
```

I followed some of the Oracle examples 
 http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/gjipx.html#gjijx or 
 http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1751/gjijx/index.html 
But all things I tried got 400 Bad Requests. 
Example:

```
curl --user admin:pwd -X POST -H "Accept: application/JSON" -H "Content-Type: application/json"
     -d '{"id":"multicastdn%2fspool","connectiondefinitionname":"multicastdns.outbound.MulticastDNSRegistry","resourceAdapterName":"MulticastDNS-connector"}'\
     http://localhost:4848/management/domain/resources/connector-connection-pool -v

# other check
curl --user admin:pwd -X POST -H "Accept: application/JSON" \
    -d id=multicastdns%2fpool \
    -d connectiondefinitionname=multicastdns.outbound.MulticastDNSRegistry \
    -d resourceAdapterName=MulticastDNS-connector \
    http://localhost:4848/management/domain/resources/connector-connection-pool -v
```

Simular results if I want to delete a existing resource.

```
curl --user admin:pwd -X DELETE -H "Accept: application/JSON" \ 
     http://localhost:4848/management/domain/resources/connector-connection-pool/multicastdns%2fpool -v

# other try
curl --user admin:pwd -X DELETE -H "Accept: application/JSON" \
     -d id=multicastdns%2fpool \
     http://localhost:4848/management/domain/resources/connector-connection-pool -v
```

Same issue if try the second step with connector resource 
     asadmin create-connector-resource --poolname multicastdns/pool jca/multicastdns

Get via REST works but add and delete an entry won't work.

Thanx florian

Comment: It is pretty late for an answer and this is not even an answer but a only a link to a testcase, which creates a connector-connection-pool in GlassFish 7: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/glassfish/blob/master/appserver/tests/admin/tests/src/test/java/org/glassfish/main/admin/test/rest/JmsITest.java It is the whole roundtrip, create connection-pool, check it, create connector resource and delete everything. I find this testcases very helpful when it comes to ReST interface of the GlassFish server.